# Free Media Player to play video with a different external audio track? Bonus if clean, easy, open source

Tags: gratis, synchronization, video-player, audio-player

Free Media Player to play video with a different external audio track? Bonus if clean, easy, open source.

Tried this, but the last step from: 
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Play_an_external_audio_track_for_a_video/
does not show up:

> Go to Audio -> Audio track -> Track 2.

(If you have more than one track available, pick the one that corresponds to the desired audio overlay.)

This is not working anymore, is too cumbersome and out of date and we would like a simpler cleaner faster method.

PS: OS - Win 8.1 x64

Answer (score 1):

[MediaPlayer Classic BE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe/) seems to be able to do this conveniently.
Just go to *Play > Audio > Load External Audio* and pick any audio file.

[image]

Comment: Gracias. Whats funny is MPC HC 64 normal that I have does not show this option :D